# Make VM accessible over RDP with pfsense

Tags: firewall, pfsense

I would like to make my VM which is in the test environment accessible from a specific Network (called FW_PRODUCTIVE) over RDP.

For doing that, I did make following steps:

1. Create 1:1 NAT Rule

> ```
> Interface = WAN
> External IP = my pulic IP address
> Internal IP = Internal IP address of my VM
> Destination IP = *
> ```

2. Create Firewall Aliases

> ```
> Name = FW_PRODUCTIVE
> Values = IP address of my producitve IP address
>
> Name = Name_Of_my_VM
> Values = Internal IP address of my VM
> ```

3. Firewall Rule (WAN)

> ```
> Protocol = IPv4 TCP
> Source = FW_PRODUCTIVE (this is an alias) 
> Port = *
> Destination = Name_Of_my_VM (this is an alias)
> Port = *
> Gateway = *
> Queue = None
> ```

**Issue:**
Unfortunately I can't connect to the VM over RDP with his public IP.

**My Questions:**

- Are there any steps missing?
- How long does it usually take, until this change affects globally? Actually Im waiting now for 3 hours.  Is there any chance to force it?
- How can I check / troubleshoot, if I did made a correct configuration? Is there any tool. I do also have already configured example for another server. This works... but it was not configured by me. So maybe I can compare these two environments together with troubleshooting tools.

Comment: I'am not used to pfsense, but the destination IP is wrote *, does that mean the firewall rewrite it to be the inside IP ? As it must be if you want the rule to work

Comment: Here is the description: `The 1:1 mapping will only be used for connections to or from the specified destination. Hint: this is usually "Any".`  - this setting is also set the same for another NAT entry, which is working well.

Comment: it should be ok, does the Windows firewall block the connection ? as it come outside the LAN by default it's blocked. Can you test without the windows firewall on

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work, even firewall is disabled. I also tried after resetting connection states, but it didn't help too.

Comment: Is FW_PRODUCTIVE an public IP range too ?

Comment: Yes it is. This is the public IP address (IPv4)  from the network, that I want to access from.